# Emailing people who didn't open a campaign

Tags: civimail

I'm looking for the simplest way to email a group of people who did not open a given civiMail campaign. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to put all the contacts that opened the mailing into a group. Then when you setup the next mailing in recipients include the group from the previous mailing and exclude the new group of contacts who opened it.